# Google maps directions service

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have an issue whith google maps directions service (api v3). I don't know how specify the origin and destination strings. For example for the requests:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=ES&languaje=es&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&origin="EJIDO+EL,ESPAÑA,04700"&destination="CORCOLLE,ITALIA,00010"

or

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=false&region=ES&languaje=es&origin="EJIDO+EL,ESPAÑA,04700"&destination="CORCOLLE,ITALIA,00010"

the response of the server is: NOT_FOUND, ie route not found,

however if I change the character Ñ by N, ie ESPAÑA by ESPANA the response is OK.

There are other places with "especial characters" for example: Göttingen, München, Köln, ....

I have been looking for information in the documentation but can not find anything about.

How can I specify the different origins and destinations?

Regards,

Francisco

Answer (score 1):

Request [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=false&region=ES&languaje=es&origin="EJIDO+EL,ESPAÑA,04700"&destination="CORCOLLE,ITALIA,00010"](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=false&region=ES&languaje=es&origin=%22EJIDO%20EL,ESPA%C3%91A,04700%22&destination=%22CORCOLLE,ITALIA,00010%22)  is true, you can test it in browser.
If you have issue in request maybe it come from URL Encoding. With special character in string URL you need encode it before do request with this string